# is there a way to cluster tweets after vectorizing them?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, tweets

I need to cluster tweets based on similarity between them, I am using **dec2vec** to vectorize them and now I need a way to cluster this vectors, also I tried **kmeans** and it wasn't a good model for me as I don't know the number of clusters. I tried to use function similarity in **gensim** library but the result is different each time and wasn't correct! So is there a way to cluster this?

Comment: It would help to provide more specifics and possibly sample data. It is really difficult to tell what issues you're facing and why the clustering algorithms you used didn't work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how many clusters you want for your particular task, before applying K-means or any other clustering algorithm. And if the number of clusters is very large, then some clustering algorithms like K-means will not be able to scale well. For large number of clusters, you could try [some other clustering algorithms](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) like agglomerative clustering or DBSCAN.

If you only need a small number of clusters but don't know the exact number of clusters, you could use [T-SNE (T-distributed Stochastic Neighbourhood Embedding)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#t-sne) to get an approximate 2-D visualisation of your vectorized tweets, to get an idea of how many clusters you would need.